# Run a program by the .bat file but not show icon and window of the program when PC is locked and it call by Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch, window, task-scheduler

I want automation with a batch file before the backup close Tresorit program and after reopen and run Tresorit program.

```
I used this code:
tasklist | find /i "tresorit.exe" && taskkill /im tresorit.exe  /F  
TIMEOUT 10

... the run backup

start %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Tresorit.lnk 
TIMEOUT 10
```

It perfect work when I run it at the PC is sign in, it show this icon in icon bar and window of the program.

But if PC is locked and I want Task Scheduler calls the batch file with admin right, unfortunately the not show icon bar of the program and I just only see it running in Task Manager.
What could I do that task scheduler Scheduler could load the icon and window of the program when the PC is locked?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How can someone see it if the PC is locked?  I am confused.

Comment: If you set time when computer goes to log off, then you are sure the time passes the computer is locked.